# Who is the headless god in this picture?

Tags: vishnu, gods, identification-request, narasimha

I recently came across this picture of Vishnu's incarnation Narasimha being worshiped by various Devas:

[image]

Most of these Devas are recognizable.  Starting from the top left and going counterclockwise, I recognize Garuda, Surya, Agni, Daksha, Shiva, Nandi, Kamadhenu, Ganesha, Kartikeya, Parvati, Brahma, Ketu, Tumburu, Vishvaksena, and Garuda.

But my question is, who is the headless god kneeling in the bottom left corner of the picture?  And how did he lose his head?

He may be associated with the two horned figures kneeling to him, if that helps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78070/discussion-on-question-by-keshav-srinivasan-who-is-the-headless-god-in-this-pict).

Comment: Where did you get this picture from ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto From a discussion group for shishyas of the Sri Vaishnava Acharya Mudhaliandan Swami.  (He is a descendant of Ramanujacharya's nephew Mudhaliandan.  I am also a descendant of Mudaliandan, but I come from a different branch of Mudhaliandan's family tree.)

Comment: Is it possible to ask them and post an answer ? Because I doubt here anyone would be able to answer this because of unclear drawing.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I did, no one knew.  In any case, it may be possible to deduce it based on identifying the gods nearby him.

Comment: Can you help me by telling me the name of the Gods who are beside him i.e. left side.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan There is one more headless creature whoes lower part is like a fish. So you can also add him for identification :-)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yes, that is Ketu in the middle of the right side.  I mentioned him in the question.

Comment: Couldn't he just be bowing too much that his head is not in perspective?

Comment: @Surya Well, his neck would at least show.

Comment: It can be raghu and ketu

Comment: @PrasannaR that's true since, Ketu is present in right side, the one on left side the OP asked is, Rahu.